# Powershell to unblock all the files in a folder

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Trying to make a .bat I can drop in a folder, when run it will unblock all the files in that folder...

```
@ECHO OFF
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {get-childitem '%~dp0' | unblock-file}"
EXIT
```

...keeps telling me "The term 'unblock-file' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet..." no matter how I try to format it, where am I going wrong?

I'm trying to do this so I can just copy the .bat to the folder (and NOT have to copy a .bat and .ps1) so I thought a 1-line powershell "call" was the way to go?

Comment: Try changing your gci to: `get-childitem { unblock-file -Path $.FullName; }`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `unblock-file` command is available from Powershell 3.0.
Upgrade your PowerShell and script should work

Comment: This cmdlet is introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0, though that may still be the issue.

Comment: Updating to PowerShell 4.0 made the original script I posted work, I followed instructions here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21016.how-to-install-windows-powershell-4-0.aspx
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Tested and working:

```
dir -r | unblock-file
```

Unblocks everything from the current directory recursively